# How to re-emit the last value of a subject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

I want to re-emit the last value of a `BehaviourSubject` to the existing subscriptions. I tried `last()`, `publishlast()`, `share()`, `refcount()`. But it doesn't trigger the existing subscriptions again with the last emitted value.

Comment: `this.subject.take(1).subscribe(item => this.subject.next(item))`? But why do you need to do this; what's the context?

Comment: This looks like it is setting up the subscriber. I want the subject to re-emit the last value.

Comment: It does, and that is what it does. It will take one value, a replay of the last value, and push it back into the subject to get re-emitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *sub* is your BehaviorSubject, this would work:

```
sub.next(sub.value)
```

Comment: You may also save some keystrokes: sub.next(sub.value)

Comment: Can anyone think of any reason this wouldn't work? In my application it definitely does not and I don't know what's different.